jQuery ajax issue with multiple forms on same page - always picks first form
I've been struggling with this (most likely simple) issue for a few days.  Any help would be appreciated.
I have a page with multiple form buttons on it for people to sign up for events. The list of form buttons is dynamically created and I'm differentiating the form buttons with the event_id value.
The jQuery code seems to always grab the topmost event_id value on the page, rather than the event_id passed within the form.
This is within a WordPress theme using jQuery and Bootstrap. Every time I submit any button it shows me in the console that the event_id = 2528.
Any help is really appreciated as I've tried everything I think.
HTML
<div class="join_race">
    <form method="post" class="join_race_form" id="join_race_form_2528">
        <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id_2528" value="2528">
        <button type="button" class="btn join btn-secondary btn-sm remove_race_btn" id="remove_race_btn_2528">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="join_race">
    <form method="post" class="join_race_form" id="join_race_form_2526">
        <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id_2526" value="2526">
        <button type="button" class="btn join btn-secondary btn-sm remove_race_btn" id="remove_race_btn_2526">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="join_race">
    <form method="post" class="join_race_form" id="join_race_form_2523">
        <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id_2523" value="2523">
        <button type="button" class="btn join btn-secondary btn-sm remove_race_btn" id="remove_race_btn_2523">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</div>

jQuery
    jQuery(".join_race_form").validate ({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var event_id = jQuery('input[name="event_id"]').val();
            var data = {
                'action': 'join_race',
                'event_id': event_id
            };


            jQuery.post(ajax.url, data, function(res) {
                var response = JSON.parse(res);
                var status = response.error;
                var join = response.join;
                var message = response.message;
                var btn_type = response.btn_type;
                if(status === false){
                    jQuery('#join_race_btn_'+ event_id ).text(join);
                    console.log(event_id);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });



When/where are you calling this script? You might look into using button.closest("form") to get the form that corresponds with the button clicked. You're not actually passing different event_ids; jQuery is still grabbing the first element that has name="event_id".

Where would you put the button.closest (''form") code? I put it here:
jQuery(".join_race_form").button.closest('form').validate ({
but no luck

I would need more context to determine that; when are you calling this script? Is it in an event listener of some sort?

jQuery('input[name="event_id"]') Has no context to the form that you're currently targeting, so it will just grab the first one from the page. Assuming that form is a reference to the form element you're currently on in the loop, then updating that to query it should fix it:
jQuery(form).find('input[name="event_id"]')
